# Buscar archivos repetidos dentro de un ArrayList en java

Tags: java, string, arraylist

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, **es posible buscar archivos con el mismo nombre o similares dentro de un ArrayList?** Por ej: Tengo un arraylist cargado con 5 archivos mp3 (en este caso son archivos de musica pero es aplicable a cualquier tipo de archivos existentes)

- Ricky Martin ft Maluma - Vente Pa Ca.
- Román El Original ft. RC - Quiero Bailar Contigo.
- Me Voy De Fiesta - Sensato Ft. Pitbull.
- Me Voy De Fiesta - Sensato Ft. Pitbull Dj Asus ft Dj Alonso.
- Chantaje - Shakira ft Maluma.

Lo que quiero hacer es realizar una búsqueda de un directorio en especifico(lo cual ya hago) y cargar todo los nombres de archivos en un arraylist para luego comparar si se repiten o son similares, en este caso dentro del array los que se repiten son:

- Me Voy De Fiesta - Sensato Ft. Pitbull.
- Me Voy De Fiesta - Sensato Ft. Pitbull Dj Asus ft Dj Alonso.

Si bien no son exactamente idénticos los nombres, lo que quiero es que independientemente de las similitudes o diferencias que exista el sistema pueda identificar esos archivos como del mismo nombre, **es posible realizar algo así en java?** Algún elemento o herramienta que posea el lenguaje para poder realizar dicha búsqueda.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda, desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo en cuenta que todos los archivos mp3 que has nombrado siguen la estructura (nombre cancion) "-" (artista o artistas) lo que yo haria seria utilizar la funcion split("-") y esta te partiria la cancion en un array de 2 celdas en la celda 0 estaria el nombre de la cancion y en la celda 1 estarian los artistas o el artista.

Despues de tener los archivos mp3 separados por nombre de cancion y artistas podras filtrar las canciones mas facilmente.

Answer (score 0):

Claro que puedes. Es cuestion de ser creativo. El unico patron que veo que se mantiene constante es:

- Me Voy De Fiesta - Sensato Ft. Pitbull.
- Me Voy De Fiesta - Sensato Ft. Pitbull Dj Asus ft Dj Alonso.

significa que "Me Voy De Fiesta -" es igual en todo los textos. El delimitador es el guion (-) por lo que puedes hacer:

- texto.split(" - ")

Eso te permitira separa el texto y luego tienes que hacer las comparaciones el cual te sugiero lo siguiente:
[Remover duplicados](https://howtodoinjava.com/java-8/java-stream-distinct-examples/)

Comment: Eso me funciono perfecto colega, pero me funciona solamente si tengo un " - " pero si no existe un guion me da error, crashea el programa, habrá algún método que valla buscando en las subcadenas las palabras que sean iguales? Porque no siempre la estructura del " - " se cumplirá me explico? Ya que podría a ver un espacio " " o cualquier otro símbolo que separe el nombre del artista. El mi pregunta puse esa estructura es verdad pero no tuve en cuenta que no siempre se cumplirá.

Comment: Esta bien.....significa que hay diferentes patrones.....entonces usa un condicional para identificar el " - " guion y ademas el espacio en blanco " "....recuerda tambien que el espacio en blanco esta repetido muchas veces..asi que te dara un poco de problema porque no tienes algo estadarizado. Mi sugerencia seria estandarizar el patron y usar un separador.....la otra seria un hashmap para guardar con clave valor....las busqueda son muy rapidas....o utilizar un List<String> titulos = new ArrayList<>(); es mas rapido que el linkedList para busqueda.....y luego complementas con stream de java8